# Error al generar build [vite:load-fallback] Could not load

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

El problema parece ser a partir de que configure el `baseUrl` para `TypeScript` y los `alias`.

### Configuración de tsconfig.json

El resto de configuración es por default la crea **vite**

```
"baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "screens/*": ["./src/screens/*"],
      "components/*": ["./src/components/*"]
    }
```

esto por si solo no funciono, por lo que tuve que configurar los alias en `vite.config.ts`, Esto también me dio algo de problemas de configurar ya que no logre comprender por si sola la documentación.

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve:{
    alias:{
      screens: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/screens'),
      components: 'src/components',
    }
  }
})
```

El proyecto es muy pequeño y lo estoy usando para probar **Vite**, pero a la hora de usar.

```
npm run build
```

me da el siguiente error.

```
[vite:load-fallback] Could not load src/components/tables/MainTable (imported by src/screens/Home.tsx): ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\USER\Documents\proyect-test\src\components\tables\MainTable'
error during build:
Error: Could not load src/components/tables/MainTable (imported by src/screens/Home.tsx): ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\USER\Documents\proyect-test\src\components\tables\MainTable'
```

Answer (score 0):

Después de varias pruebas, intento y errores, he resuelto el problema, unicamente cambiando la configuración de `vite.config.ts` que es cambiar el `resolve` del `alias`, quedando de la siguiente manera.

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve:{
    alias:{
      screens: resolve('./src/screens'),
      components: resolve('src/components'),
    }
  }
})
```

Aun recibo algún par advertencias, pero nada que detenga el build.

**Advertencias recibidas**. Si alguien sabe como solventarlas, con gusto acepto la ayuda.

```
Some chunks are larger than 500 KiB after minification. Consider:
- Using dynamic import() to code-split the application
- Use build.rollupOptions.output.manualChunks to improve chunking: https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#outputmanualchunks
- Adjust chunk size limit for this warning via build.chunkSizeWarningLimit.
```

De momento esto resuelve el problema para generar el build.